# Is it correct to cast a pointer to pointer to pointer to int to a pointer to pointer to pointer to double?

Tags: c

I have a function which deallocates a cubic matrix of `double`:

```
free_matrix(double ***U, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            free(U[i][j]);
        }
        free(U[i]);
    }
    free(U);
}
```

Then I have a cubic matrix of integer `int ***matrix;`. Compiler gives me an error when I call `free_matrix(matrix,n)` but I don't want to duplicate the previous function which only deallocates elements. Is it correct/good/safe to simply cast it like this?

```
free_matrix((double ***)matrix,n);
```

Comment: No, it isn't, because pointers for different types are not guaranteed to be the same size. What you should do is implement a type-generic macro whose body is the code you have. Something a la `#define FREE_MAT(T) free_matrix_ ## T (T **U, int n){...}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately not; per 6.2.5p28:

> [...] Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements.

So there is no guarantee that a `int **` can be indexed the same way as a `double **`, because `int *` and `double *` might e.g. have different sizes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Then the problem is when I use U[i] and U[i][j] which are not guaranteed to point to the start of the array.

Answer (score 0):

What you propose is in general not safe, as noted by @ecatmur. I would rather try to change the interface of your C function to something like the following (I assume 2D for simplicity):

```
int    ** imatrix_alloc(size_t nrows, size_t ncols);
double ** dmatrix_alloc(size_t nrows, size_t ncols);
void      matrix_free  (void * matrix);
```

and use it in client code like:

```
int    ** imat = imatrix_alloc(10,20);
double ** fmat = dmatrix_alloc(30,20);
...
matrix_free(imat);
matrix_free(fmat);
```

The tricky point in the allocation will be to pre-compute all the space you need and allocate it with a single call to `malloc`. Then you should initialized pointers appropriately. If you do this `matrix_free` can be implemented as a simple wrapper to free:

```
void matrix_free  (void * matrix) {
  free(matrix);
}
```